# jQuery .animate not working after hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make a menu for my website. I want to achieve that the menu items go right and back when hovered over, or off respectively. But nothing is happening whatsoever.
This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".item").hover(function(){
            $(this).animate({
                right: "-=100px";
                }, "slow";
            );
            , $(this).animate({
                right: "+=100px";
                }, "slow";
            );
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: you need to use two functions separated by comma

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your syntax is incorrect.

You may also want to use `on("mouseover")` instead of `hover()`, because I believe that you don't want to start the animation on `mouseout`. That will happen if you use `hover`.

Another thing is that you don't want to run the animation if it's currently running. That would result in some unexpected behavior.

Here's the code with correct syntax with `mouseover`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".item").on("mouseover", function () {

        // run the animation only if the item is NOT animating
        if (!$(this).is(':animated')) {

            $(this).animate({
                right: "-=100px"
            }, "slow", function () {
                // first animation completed
                $(this).animate({
                    right: "+=100px"
                }, "slow");
            });

        }

    });

});
```

I made a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/131o4hb0/4/